# Highlight street sections with Google Map API or OpenStreetMap?

Tags: label, openstreetmap

So I am a novice with coding, but I have found my way around everything enough to run a web design and development freelance operation that builds wordpress sites for news companies, blogs and small non-php websites for local artists, scientists, and writers.  So while I am a novice, I think I can figure a lot of stuff out.  Maybe you all can show me the beginning of where to start to find out how to do this mini project of mine...

I want to use google map api or openstreetmap to highlight specific sections of streets throughout my city, Philadelphia.  I want the highlighted streets to be categorized as "awesome streets" or "shitty streets" and I want each side of the street to be recognized as such.  How do I do this?  What article or example can I run at and see if I can make it work?

I also need these "street labels" to searchable in the future so that someone might come in and say "Find the nearest shitty street" and then get directions to the nearest point on the nearest shitty street.  This second part can be done in the future... but my first task is to label all the streets and all the street sides.

Any thoughts?  Google Maps the best for this? Or OpenStreetMap?

THANKS!